# Cambiar idioma ascii a utf8 en neatsbean

Tags: java

[image]Hoy he ido a ejecurtar un programa y las tildes y las ñ en un string ya no me las lee.
Sabeis como puedo hacer para cambiar el idioma del teclado en neatbean a utf8

he intentado poner codigos en neatsbean.conf pero no me han servido

Comment: Por casualidad te refieres a [tag:netbeans] [(enlace externo)](https://netbeans.org/)?

Comment: No, acambo de añadir un ejemplo a mi problema las ñ y las tildes no me las reconoce neatsbean

Comment: Este problema fue planteado de manera similar aqui. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943152/string-decode-utf-8
Creditos: @ItayMaman